# how to split csv into parts using column names?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large csv data file that I want to split using columns. That is, some specified columns get into one part, some other columns into another part. I also want to be able to create more than 2 parts. How can I do this in python? Also, is there a library in python to handle many data formats?

Input Format:

```
policyID statecode county eq_site_limit hu_site_limit fl_site_limit fr_site_limit tiv_2011 tiv_2012 eq_site_deductible hu_site_deductible fl_site_deductible fr_site_deductible point_latitude point_longitude line construction point_granularity

119736 FL CLAY COUNTY 498960 498960 498960 498960 498960 792148.9 0 9979.2 0 0 30.102261 -81.711777 Residential Masonry 1
448094 FL CLAY COUNTY 1322376.3 1322376.3 1322376.3 1322376.3 1322376.3 1438163.57 0 0 0 0 30.063936 -81.707664 Residential Masonry 3
206893 FL CLAY COUNTY 190724.4 190724.4 190724.4 190724.4 190724.4 192476.78 0 0 0 0 30.089579 -81.700455 Residential Wood 1
333743 FL CLAY COUNTY 0 79520.76 0 0 79520.76 86854.48 0 0 0 0 30.063236 -81.707703 Residential Wood 3
172534 FL CLAY COUNTY 0 254281.5 0 254281.5 254281.5 246144.49 0 0 0 0 30.060614 -81.702675 Residential Wood 1
```

Input Format Columns :

```
policyID statecode county eq_site_limit hu_site_limit fl_site_limit fr_site_limit tiv_2011 tiv_2012 eq_site_deductible hu_site_deductible fl_site_deductible fr_site_deductible point_latitude point_longitude line construction point_granularity
```

Output Format Columns:

Part A: `['policyID', 'statecode', 'county', 'eq_site_limit', 'hu_site_limit']`

Part B: `['fl_site_limit', 'fr_site_limit', 'tiv_2011', 'tiv_2012', 'eq_site_deductible', 'hu_site_deductible', 'fl_site_deductible', 'fr_site_deductible', 'point_latitude', 'point_longitude', 'line', 'construction', 'point_granularity']`

Code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("FL_insurance_sample.csv")
cl_list = list(df.columns.values)
a = cl_list[:5]
b = cl_list[5:]

with open('data1.csv', 'w') as datafile:
    for x in a:
        saved_column = df[x]
        datafile.write(saved_column)

with open('data2.csv', 'w') as datafile:
    for x in b:
        saved_column = df[x]
        datafile.write(saved_column)
```

Comment: We would need to see a sample of the csv file, and of code you've written in an attempt to process it.

Comment: Also some indication of the format the output must have.

Comment: What does "many data formats" mean?

Comment: I mean csv as well as other possible formats in which datasets are provided.

Comment: "Other possible formats" is too broad. Also, request for recommending software libraries are ff topic on SO.

Comment: Ok thanks, where can I get the recommendation for a library? I haven't been able to get much using google.

Comment: See my answer to split data-frame based upon specific columns. And using column names you can split them out of order also. i.e. A,C,D,B instead of A,B,C,D. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to split specific columns from your original data-frame to new dataframes and then onto `csv`.
Let me know if this assumption is not correct, as the answer is based on that.

OK, So  you read `csv` to a pandas dataframe (df)

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("FL_insurance_sample.csv")
```

Then, create a new df based on your needs (taking your part A here)

```
>>> part_A = df.filter(['policyID', 'statecode', 'county', 'eq_site_limit', 'hu_site_limit'], axis=1)

>>> part_A
   policyID statecode       county  eq_site_limit  hu_site_limit
0       NaN       NaN          NaN            NaN            NaN
1  119736.0        FL  CLAY COUNTY       498960.0      498960.00
2  448094.0        FL  CLAY COUNTY      1322376.3     1322376.30
3  206893.0        FL  CLAY COUNTY       190724.4      190724.40
4  333743.0        FL  CLAY COUNTY            0.0       79520.76
5  172534.0        FL  CLAY COUNTY            0.0      254281.50
```

Send part_A df data to csv

```
>>> part_A.to_csv("part_A.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Similarly create a new df for part_B

```
>>> part_B = df.filter(['fl_site_limit', 'fr_site_limit', 'tiv_2011', 'tiv_2012', 'eq_site_deductible', 'hu_site_deductible', 'fl_site_deductible', 'fr_site_deductible', 'point_latitude', 'point_longitude', 'line', 'construction', 'point_granularity'], axis=1)
```

Then send part_B df to csv.

```
>>> part_B.to_csv("part_B.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Thus you can split columns based upon your needs and send to `csv`.

Answer (score 1):

To write any list of columns into a CSV file, use function `to_csv()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("FL_insurance_sample.csv")

df.iloc[:,:5].to_csv("data1.csv")
df.iloc[:,5:].to_csv("data2.csv")
```

If you want to pass a list of columns directly:

```
df[a].to_csv("data1.csv")
df[b].to_csv("data2.csv")
```

Comment: If I wanted to mention column names instead of doing `:5`, how would I do that?

Comment: See the updated answer.